# Page refresh on JS alert - can't focus on text input

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I've noticed on Chrome and Edge that if I have a javascript confirm (or alert or prompt) message fire, and the user refreshes the page instead of clicking the ok/cancel button, any textfield on the page cannot be edited.

```html
<html>
<body>
<input name="input" value="Can you type here?" />
<script>
console.log("document has focus = "+document.hasFocus())        
if(document.hasFocus()==true){
    confirm("Refresh this page, do not click cancel or ok");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It's as if refreshing on the popup completely blurs Chrome, so the only way to get it back into focus is to click out from the app and back in again. Even constant refreshing by ctrl-R won't put the focus back.

By forcing focus onto the textfield onload, the textfield will have focus but I still can't type into the box, as the browser itself is out of focus.

Has anyone seen this before? A colleague and I couldn't find any mention of this online, apologies if it's been answered.

I'm on Windows 7
Chrome 91.0.4472.77
Edge 90.0.818.46

On my Mac (Chrome 90.0.4430.212) I cannot replicate this.

Cheers

Comment: I can reproduce the issue on Windows. It looks like an issue with Windows chromium browser. I suggest that you can report the issue on [chromium issues site](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines).

Comment: Good idea, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just posting for the record that I raised this as a bug and it's been merged into an existing bug that I didn't find when searching. As yet no fix on the Chromium side but hopefully will see a fix in future.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1085949